# CLion does not recognise c++17 features

Tags: c++, c++17, clion

I am using CLion with c++17 project, i am trying to use

```
std::map<int, std::string> m{ {10, "potato"}, {1, "banana"} };
auto nodeHandler = m.extract(10);
```

However CLion keep complaining about exctract not being member of map.

How can i force CLion to use/recognise c++17 features?

CMake:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)
project(untitled2)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

add_executable(untitled2 main.cpp)
```

Comment: What your IDE complains about is irrelevant. What matters is what your *compiler* is capable of. Remember to tell it to enable C++17 by passing it the right options (for GCC and Clang that would be `-std=c++17`).

Comment: Are you sure you are compiling with C++17? For example in CMake this would be `set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)`

Comment: Please show corresponding cmake file. Also note that clion has rather poor syntax highlighting / type deduction capabilities so you should not expect much from it.

Comment: added Cmake file

Comment: What compiler are you using? And version?

Comment: I am running CLion on windows, using  MinGW, i updated all libraries so it should be latest version. -> mingw32-gcc-g++ version 6.3.0-1

Comment: mingw32-gcc-g++ version 6.3.0-1

Comment: Compiler is not relevant because clion always relies on bundled clangd. You may want to send a bug report. Though it would probably be a good idea to switch to different IDE.

Comment: Seems you need to rename `m` -> `m1`. Or back :)

Comment: thats jsut ,typo, but thanks for noticing

Comment: @VTT Any IDE suggestions?